‘The preLaunchTask ‘C/C++: g++.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1’
I’m encountering an issue while debugging C++ in VSCode. When I press ‘Run C++ file’, I get the error: ‘The preLaunchTask ‘C/C++: g++.exe build active file’ terminated with exit code -1’.The error
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Followed the ‘Getting Started with Visual Studio Code’ instructions.
Verified that gcc, g++, and gdb are installed by checking their versions in Command Prompt.
Installed and uninstalled ‘MSYS2’ multiple times, resulting in several instances of ‘MSYS2’ in my ‘Installed apps’ section on Windows.multiple installations of ‘MSYS2’

I suspect the multiple installations of ‘MSYS2’ might be causing this issue. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
More details:

My path (User variables&system variables)
The output of VS code
My Tasks.json(This is created by the C++ extension)


Show your tasks.json and launch.json, if any. Also show the output you get in the terminal along with this error. Windows showing multiple installations of MSYS2 isn't a problem, I have that too and everything works fine.

@HolyBlackCat Thank you for your response. I have added more details about my issue in the poster. I hope you can take a look. Thanks!

Rename the file to only contain latin characters, no chinese (I assume that's what that is?). And the same thing for the directory it's in, and all the parent directories. If that doesn't work, move it off onedrive, and somewhere without spaces in path.

@HolyBlackCat You are right, thank you. I had not considered this possibility because I used to use Xcode, which does not have this problem.
For those who are experiencing the same issue:
I tested three possible factors suggested by HolyBlackCat (Chinese characters, ‘OneDrive’, and spaces), and I discovered that the issue is solely due to Chinese characters in the path, not ‘OneDrive’ or spaces.
